# Java structure holding multiple variables that can be written and read as an integer?

Tags: java

I am sure this exists, and I believe I did something similar in C quite a while back with bit fields, but I cannot think of how I should do this.

Basically I will have a series of options that can either be on or off. These options describe the operations an application can perform on a file e.g.

```
STRUCTURE
{
  EXECUTE
  READ
  WRITE
}
```

If this structure were a bit field I would like to be able to set structure to a value that represents both READ and WRITE but not execute (e.g. 3). If I were to read this structure it could give me 3 thus I would know that given this value execute should be denied. A bit field solution may not necessarily be the best solution in this case though.

Comment: [Effective Java #32](http://dhruba.name/2008/12/31/effective-java-item-32-use-enumset-instead-of-bit-fields/) suggest using an `EnumSet`

Comment: Or, of course, just use an object with boolean fields. Objects are Java's closest equivalent of C structs, or vice versa.

Comment: if you want to do it the c-way you can use powers of 2 and | (bitwise or)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely an EnumSet, as 'zapl' recommended.

Or have a List of Enum, but the latter makes more sense.